# CAGradient layer on UIImageview moving upwards in iphone 6s plus while setting correctly in iphone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uikit, cagradientlayer

In my viewDidLoad I am calling method:

```
[self applyGradientOnDogImageView];

-(void)applyGradientOnDogImageView{

CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];

gradient.frame = CGRectMake(self.dogImageView.bounds.origin.x, self.dogImageView.bounds.origin.y+self.dogImageView.bounds.size.height/2, self.dogImageView.bounds.size.width, self.dogImageView.bounds.size.height/2);

gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(__bridge id)[[UIColor clearColor] CGColor], (__bridge id)[[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1.0] CGColor], nil];

[self.dogImageView.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
```

}

In iphone 5 I am getting this output:

[image]

In iphone 6s plus getting this output:
[image]

How to fix this problem of gradient moving upwards in iphone 6s plus?

Comment: That is a funny-looking dog! :)

Comment: @Duncan and the name is Tiger ;)

Comment: are you using autolayout with the imageview? When is the function you are showing called?

Comment: @ Maurice : yes imageview  is set using autolayout. [self applyGradientOnDogImageView] is called in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Unusal looking tiger as well.

Comment: So you call applyGradientOnDogImageView to adjust an image of a Koala that's labeled as a tiger. In addition to needing iOS help, I think you might need to find a Stack Exchange sight on animal taxonomy. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In viewDidLoad the views haven't been sized to the specific device. Therefore the frame for your gradient is going to be wrong.

You should call code that depends on layouts being correct in `viewWillAppear`, and you should also adjust them in your `viewDidLayoutSubviews` method.

So instead of calling your applyGradient method from viewDidLoad, call it from `viewWillAppear`, and also write code that updates the layer frame and call THAT from `viewDidLayoutSubViews`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me. The link provided by @Jerry was also helpful. So my final solution was a mix of both Duncan and Jerry 's solution.

Answer (score 1):

The image is being resized after your layer is created, but the layer is not. The easiest way to fix this is to make a UIView subclass that has the layer in it. Then you can respond to the size change and resize the layer

Comment: Similar to this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29111099/calayer-not-resizing-with-autolayout