# Gradients do not work on objects positioned by Auto Layout Xcode Swift

Tags: ios, swift, gradient, ios-autolayout

I am trying to add a gradient to a view. However the view is positioned using Auto Layout, and therefore the gradient can no longer be applied to the object. What should I do?

This is the gradient function:

```
func setGradientBackground() {

  let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
  gradient.frame = bounds
  gradient.colors = [
  UIColor(red: 143/255, green: 162/255, blue: 217/255, alpha:1).cgColor,
  UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 141/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1).cgColor
  ]
  gradient.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
  gradient.startPoint = CGPoint(x:0, y:0)
  gradient.endPoint = CGPoint(x:1, y:1)

  layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
 }
```

And this is the code for adding the Object

```
let testView = UIView()

testView.setGradientBackground()
self.view.addSubview(testView)

testView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

testView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
testView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
testView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
testView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Use this custom gradient view https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app/37243106#37243106

Comment: This is the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3679858/calayer-autoresizing-on-iphone-ipad-how/4111917#4111917

Comment: `testView` has frame equal to .zero so gradient layer will also have the same frame. Hence you will not see anything. Initialize `testView` with some non zero frame to see the effect.

Comment: @Kamran Yeah true, but if I initialize the testView with some temporary non zero properties, then my actual constraints will not work? Or could your give an example of how to fix the code ?

Comment: Yes, I can provide the fix if you can share some more information like who is the parent where this code is added, ViewController or UIView? From where you are calling this code?

Comment: @Kamran Great! The "setGradientBackground" is a function inside a UIKit extension. And all the "Testview" content is inside the viewdidload of a regular Viewcontroller. Tell me if you want more info, like a screenshot from the code or something/If I should upload all the code?

Comment: Remove `testView.setGradientBackground()` from `viewDidLoad`. Make `testview` as class member and override this method in `ViewController`. `override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        testView.setGradientBackground()
    }`.

Comment: @kamran Awesome! Thanks for the help :)

Comment: `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will run every time there is a layout change, so you don't want to add a new gradient every time.  Check if you've already added the gradient and just update its frame on second and later calls.

Comment: @vacawama Sounds reasonable, how would I do that?

Comment: Make a subclass of UIView and override `layoutSubviews`.  Check out what this person did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51543676/1630618

Comment: @vacawama, Perfect, thanks :)